# how do we run automated ui tests using jenkins and nightwatch?

Tags: jenkins, nightwatch.js

I am trying to get the automated ui tests to run using jenkins on a node. How can I get that going using nightwatch.js?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a blog post that uses Nightwatch with Jenkins, it might help you; https://juristr.com/blog/2014/02/nightwatch-test-automation/

It contains an introduction for running Nightwatch tests and how to run the tests automatically in Jenkins.

In Nightwatch;

> On Windows it is suggested to create a nightwatch.js at the root of your project which requires the binary from the node_modules.
>
> require('nightwatch/bin/runner.js');
>
> In this way you can invoke the runner as follows:
>
> $ node nightwatch.js

In Jenkins you will have to do the following to run Nightwatch ;
[image: Nightwatch config in Jenkins]